# Почему вылезает ошибка not a GROUP BY expression в Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, group-by, oracle-apex

Имеется код в Oracle

```
SELECT SN.NAME, QUANTITY, SALE_DAT, PRICE, P.NAME FROM SALEMAN SN, 
SALEMAP SP, PRICELIST PL, PRODUCTS P
GROUP BY SN.NAME, QUANTITY, SALE_DAT, PRICE, P.NAME
HAVING SN.MEN_PERS_CODE = SP.MEN_PERS_CODE AND
SP.PROD_ID = PL.PROD_ID AND
PL.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID;
```

Вроде запрос оформлен правильно. Почему вылезает ошибка not a GROUP BY expression?

Comment: *Вроде запрос оформлен правильно.* Только вроде. MEN_PERS_CODE и PROD_ID (во всех таблицах) не включены в выражение группировки и не обрамлены групповыми функциями. И вообще - нахрена группировка?

Comment: MEN_PERS_CODE и PROD_ID (во всех таблицах) это внешние ключи. Их я использую для связи таблиц.

Comment: А что вообще ваш запрос делает? В том виде, как он у вас написан, вам надо `GROUP BY` выкинуть вообще, а вместо `HAVING` написать `WHERE`. Это будет хотя бы выглядеть осмысленно.

Comment: *MEN_PERS_CODE и PROD_ID (во всех таблицах) это внешние ключи. Их я использую для связи таблиц.* И как связана эта фраза с тем, что было сказано? по мне - никак, от слова "вообще".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAVING используется в сочетании с GROUP BY, чтобы ограничить группы возвращаемых строк, только тех, чьи условия истинны

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT SN.NAME, QUANTITY, SALE_DAT, PRICE, P.NAME FROM SALEMAN SN, 
SALEMAP SP, PRICELIST PL, PRODUCTS P
GROUP BY SN.NAME, QUANTITY, SALE_DAT, PRICE, P.NAME, 
         SN.MEN_PERS_CODE, SP.MEN_PERS_CODE, SP.PROD_ID, PL.PROD_ID, P.PROD_ID
HAVING SN.MEN_PERS_CODE = SP.MEN_PERS_CODE AND
SP.PROD_ID = PL.PROD_ID AND
PL.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
```

ИЛИ

```
SELECT SN.NAME, QUANTITY, SALE_DAT, PRICE, P.NAME FROM SALEMAN SN, 
SALEMAP SP, PRICELIST PL, PRODUCTS P
WHERE SN.MEN_PERS_CODE = SP.MEN_PERS_CODE AND
SP.PROD_ID = PL.PROD_ID AND
PL.PROD_ID = P.PROD_ID
GROUP BY SN.NAME, QUANTITY, SALE_DAT, PRICE, P.NAME
```